# How can I index my x and y variables so I can get one plot at a time?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to plot three graphs, which I obtain with the code below but I would to make one plot at a time instead of all three at once (maybe by indexing my x and y variables ? I do not know, please click to see screenshot)

[image]

```
for i in range(0, n-1): 
    k1y = dt*v[i]
    k1v = dt*Pendulum(y[i],t[i],v[i],F)
    k2y = dt*(v[i]+0.5*k1v)
    k2v = dt*Pendulum(y[i]+0.5*dt, t[i]+0.5*k1y, v[i]+0.5*k1v,F)
    k3y = dt*(v[i]+0.5*k2v)
    k3v = dt*Pendulum(y[i]+0.5*dt, t[i]+0.5*k2y, v[i]+0.5*k2v,F)
    k4y = dt*(v[i]+k3v)
    k4v = dt*Pendulum(y[i] + dt, t[i] + k3y, v[i] + k3v,F)

# Update next value of y 
    y[i+1] = y[i] + (k1y + 2 * k2y + 2 * k3y + k4y) / 6.0 
    v[i+1] = v[i] + (k1v + 2 * k2v + 2 * k3v + k4v) / 6.0
    t[i+1] = t[i] + dt

    if y[i+1] > np.pi:
        y[i+1] = y[i+1] - 2*np.pi
    elif y[i+1] < -np.pi:
        y[i+1] = y[i+1] + 2*np.pi

plt.plot(t, y,'-r')
plt.title("$\\theta$ versus time")
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Angle [rad]')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you want to plot one graph, then wait for user to press any key, then plot second and so on?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do

Comment: Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is to create a new figure for every plot, like so (inside your for loop):

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, y,'-r')
plt.title("$\\theta$ versus time")
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Angle [rad]')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you need.

```
for i in range(0, n-1): 
    k1y = dt*v[i]
    k1v = dt*Pendulum(y[i],t[i],v[i],F)
    k2y = dt*(v[i]+0.5*k1v)
    k2v = dt*Pendulum(y[i]+0.5*dt, t[i]+0.5*k1y, v[i]+0.5*k1v,F)
    k3y = dt*(v[i]+0.5*k2v)
    k3v = dt*Pendulum(y[i]+0.5*dt, t[i]+0.5*k2y, v[i]+0.5*k2v,F)
    k4y = dt*(v[i]+k3v)
    k4v = dt*Pendulum(y[i] + dt, t[i] + k3y, v[i] + k3v,F)

# Update next value of y 
    y[i+1] = y[i] + (k1y + 2 * k2y + 2 * k3y + k4y) / 6.0 
    v[i+1] = v[i] + (k1v + 2 * k2v + 2 * k3v + k4v) / 6.0
    t[i+1] = t[i] + dt

    if y[i+1] > np.pi:
        y[i+1] = y[i+1] - 2*np.pi
    elif y[i+1] < -np.pi:
        y[i+1] = y[i+1] + 2*np.pi

plt.plot(t, y,'-r')
plt.title("$\\theta$ versus time")
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Angle [rad]')
plt.show()
while not plt.waitforbuttonpress(): pass # This will wait until the user presses any keyboard key
```